# check if audio and video device is connected using javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, video, twilio, webrtc

I am building a video call web platform using twilio video API, we have requirement that before the user joins the call we have to check if user has audio and video device connected to his computer, if user doesn't have any one of those, then don't allow user to join the video call.

I already tried **mediaDevices.enumerateDevices** from https://webrtc.org/getting-started/media-devices .Below is the code,

```
function getConnectedDevices(type, callback) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
    .then(devices => {
        console.log(devices);
        callback(filtered);
    });
}
```

This gives me below json,

```
[{
    deviceId: "default",
    groupId: "10684f807204708d605cc3ad0e5c4eaf763f1440775b8f79cdecf72806cc82f5",
    kind: "audioinput",
    label: "Default - Microphone (Realtek Audio)"
},
{
    deviceId: "communications",
    groupId: "10684f807204708d605cc3ad0e5c4eaf763f1440775b8f79cdecf72806cc82f5",
    kind: "audioinput",
    label: "Communications - Microphone (Realtek Audio)"
},
{
    deviceId: "491ccf0569924a7c1264a6afd337a8f744f239d78414e80f17a07122725bb46c",
    groupId: "10684f807204708d605cc3ad0e5c4eaf763f1440775b8f79cdecf72806cc82f5",
    kind: "audioinput",
    label: "Microphone (Realtek Audio)"
},
{
    deviceId: "823160fcdef4bedf2d1769cfbcb9058fe41bc01258b811f9aef19eb21a27cb76",
    groupId: "f86216b491186ac3208f9fc59d31b913e7017bafb505005d39983345ab35811f",
    kind: "videoinput",
    label: "Integrated Webcam (0bda:5689)"
},
{
    deviceId: "default",
    groupId: "10684f807204708d605cc3ad0e5c4eaf763f1440775b8f79cdecf72806cc82f5",
    kind: "audiooutput",
    label: "Default - Speakers / Headphones (Realtek Audio)"
},
{
    deviceId: "communications",
    groupId: "10684f807204708d605cc3ad0e5c4eaf763f1440775b8f79cdecf72806cc82f5",
    kind: "audiooutput",
    label: "Communications - Speakers / Headphones (Realtek Audio)"
},
{
    deviceId: "213851f9659d4751c7c60016112d74e290d1ce398d12d774bda0c68ef590f61c",
    groupId: "10684f807204708d605cc3ad0e5c4eaf763f1440775b8f79cdecf72806cc82f5",
    kind: "audiooutput",
    label: "Speakers / Headphones (Realtek Audio)"
}
]
```

By looking at the json i do not exactly understand how to check for audio and video devices available. Since i have to implement this in angular i dont want to use jquery or any pluggin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your computer doesn't have any audio or video devices connected, then this array will be empty. It looks like you've got a few devices connected already here.

What you want to look for is `audioinput` for microphones and `videoinput` for cameras.

So you could do something like this:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
    .then(devices => {
        const microphones = devices.filter(d => d.kind === 'audioinput');
        const cameras = devices.filter(d => d.kind === 'videoinput');
        callback(
          microphones,
          cameras
        );
    });
```

if `cameras.length > 0` then you've got a camera of some sort attached, and if `microphones.length > 0` then you've got some sort of microphone attached. You could use that to check to see if you want to allow someone onto the call.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. This is a good answer, I just wanted to add one further point. Which is that some platforms (particularly iOS) will not give you results from `enumerateDevices` until you have requested access to a camera or microphone through `getUserMedia` first.

Comment: Thanks @philnash for sharing your insight. So it looks like, if one had to detect the presence of a device in iOS (and some other similar platforms) one should access for it? And if there's an exception/failure, one needs to infer that the required device is absent.

Comment: You can run `getUserMedia` to ask for camera or microphone access, you can even give some direction, like asking for `facingMode: “user”` for example. But the promise may reject because it doesn’t exist or because the user denied permission and you’d need to handle both outcomes (though you may handled them the same). Once you have been granted permission the first time, you can then enumerate all devices.